Powershell Script Closing after 24 Hrs of Idle time
I have a powershell script that monitors the folder for file generation and did some action if file is generated, basically a "Folder Monitor" using powershell script.
I'm triggering that script using command prompt and running it using Adminstrator Account.
But problem is that Powershell script is closing after 24 hrs from last logout. I have to login again restart the scripts to keep running.
Is there a solution so that I keep running it 24/7?
Intially I was triggering the script using non-admin user and later I updated the script to execute using highest level of permissions. But still I'm facing same issue.

How are you launching the script? I know that Task scheduler will auto-terminate a script after 24 hours.

I'm initiating the script using the batch file, it stays in the task manager running in the background. After 24hrs of logoff by user script closes

What do you mean by logoff? Because the moment you do start->shutdown->logoff, the script will stop directly.

I've setup the script in RDP machine and I'm disconnect from the server by logging off. Server still runs but from the time I logoff from the server within 24hrs if I don't login again script stops running in background

What if you just disconnect, but keep the session logged on? If that is not what you want, you'll need to post the script so we can debug it.
